# ASP.NET 2 Core 'Application state data' not storing data between requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

As described in the [MSDN library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x#application-state-data) in the topic 'Application state data' I want to store data and make them available to all users. As in the msdn example, I have registered my custom service called `MyShardData` in the Startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    [...]
    services.AddSingleton<MyShardData>();
    [...]
}
```

The service class is very simple:

```
public class MyShardData
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I want to share a message between two requests:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(MyShardData pMyShardData)
    {
        return Content(pMyShardData.Message);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult SetMessage(MyShardData pMyShardData, string pMessage)
    {
        pMyShardData.Message = pMessage;

        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

In the first request, I put the message 'Hello World' and pass the value to a the property of the service. In a second request, I want to get the value back. The problem: The value is null:

[image]

The method 'AddSingleton' let me think, that MySharedData will be cached in the memory because it is handled as singleton. And because it is a singleton, I think, I do not need to save the message in a static property. What is wrong here?

Comment: Create a constructor on your `TestController` and have `MyShardData pMyShardData` as parameter. Remove `MyShardData pMyShardData` on your two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject the service you registered by declaring a dependency in the controller's constructor. Also, keep in mind that your singleton will not prevent ASP.NET from shutting down due to things like idle timeout. You're better off using external third-party solutions for persisting state (Redis, SQL Server, etc).

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyShardData _myShardData;
    public TestController(MyShardData myShardData)
    {
         _myShardData = myShardData;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content(_myShardData.Message);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult SetMessage(string pMessage)
    {
        _myShardData.Message = pMessage;

        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Frank Nielsen said: Inject the service in you're controllers constructor like so:

```
private MyShardData _pMyShardData;

public TestController(MyShardData pMyShardData){
    _pMyShardData = pMyShardData;
}
```

Then you can set and return it with a private field:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Content(_pMyShardData.Message);
}

[HttpPut]
public IActionResult SetMessage(string pMessage)
{
    _pMyShardData.Message = pMessage;

    return NoContent();
}
```